# Multichannel Audio & Rec. 709 HD Standards

Tags: android, google-tv

I had some more advanced questions which I couldn't find answers to. My company does both television production and Android development, so Google TV is a natural progression for us. We have a Logitech Revue for website development testing, however, we were unable to make Google IO and get onboard with "FishTank" for app development. I hope there are opportunities for other developers to get on board because we have some great ideas we are looking forward to implement!

### Multichannel Audio Support

I notice there is decode support for DTS / AC3 (Dolby Digital) and encode support for AC3 (Dolby Digital) listed in [Supported Media Formats](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats.html). However, there is no information regarding more then 2 channels (Stereo) of audio.  Would there be encode support for more then 2 Channels? Such as 5.1 or 7.1? Would these discretely accessible? Could we generate multichannel surround resource files in tools such as ProTools?

### Rec. 709 HD Luminance Standards

Do our resources have to confirm to Rec. 709 Luminance Standards? Where reference black is 16 and reference white is 235? Or are the graphics luminance ranges remapped automatically? I also have the same question regarding encoded material in MPEG-2?

For more information on Rec. 709, check out this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709).

### Overscan and addressable space

I've read the Display Guidelines and was not clear on if Andriod binds you to the display dimensions set during the user screen measurement phase. If it does, could this be overridden? Most television content is already generated with overscan in mind.

Thanks so much! I'm really looking forward to developing!

Scott

*I originally posted this on the Google TV Group, this is probably a more appropriate place.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AC3 Encoder:
The AC3 encoder is only available for mixing AC3 stream with Android audio. It maybe possible to play multi-channel audio through AudioFlinger because it does not explicit limit the number of tracks to two. We haven't tested it and engineering isn't hopeful. At the moment there is no way to play multi-channel audio other than embedding AC3 or DTS stream in a proper media container and play it on the MediaPlayer interface.

If it does work internally, it will depend on each OEM's implementation to actually get to the speakers.

Rec. 709:
On the Intel platform, the output is configured for Rec. 709 and the RGB graphics pixels are automatically converted from full RGB to Rec. 709. The color space meta data in the video stream is passed by the decoder to the renderer and converted to Rec. 709 automatically.

Graphics resources should be authored in full RGB space.
MPEG-2 video should be encoded in Rec. 709. If it is SD content, it should probably be left at its original Rec. 601 color space and let the hardware perform the conversion.

Overscan
Android does bind you to the display dimensions set durring the user screen measurement phase.  It's not possible to override.

Comment: Regarding AC3 Encoding, it sounds like we will not be able to rely on dynamically generating surround sound mixes at this time, but will be alowed to play AC3 streams in MediaPlayer.  Does this have to be in a wrapper?

Comment: Regarding Rec. 709, we could access the full RGB if we encoded it as such with the proper MPEG-2 Encoder? Does the conversion happen by clipping at 16 to 235 or is it scaled to fit within that range?